# Code to replace CRC32 included in existing library

Tags: stm32, crc32

I'm trying to CRC32 with STM32L151. 
I wrote the code with an existing library. But I don't want to use the CRC32 code included in the existing library. I want to create my own. How can I derive the correct code from this code?

I didn't look up the CRC32 calculations on the data sheet. Let me know if you know how to calculate.

```
uint16_t Checksum(uint8_t *check_buffer, uint8_t buffer_legnth) {
  uint8_t i;
  uint16_t crc_result = 0;

  LL_CRC_ResetCRCCalculationUnit(CRC);

  for (i = 0; i < buffer_legnth; i++) {
    LL_CRC_FeedData32(CRC, check_buffer[i]);
  }

  crc_result = (LL_CRC_ReadData32(CRC) & 0x0000FFFF);

  // printf("CRC : %X \r\n", crc_result);

  return crc_result;
}

union Crc_Data {
  uint8_t Crc_Data_8[2];
  uint16_t Crc_Data_16;
}

void main() {
  union Crc_Data Crc_Data;
  uint8_t test_packet[8] = {0x10, 0x20, 0x30, 0xB9, 0x53, 0x23, 0xA3};
  Crc_Data.Crc_Data_16 = xcrc32((uint8_t *)&test_packet, 7);
  printf("CRC = %02x %02x \r\n", Crc_Data.Crc_Data_8[0],
         Crc_Data.Crc_Data_8[1]);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the library? Do you want to use the hardware CRC?

Comment: There's not enough code to know for sure, but based on what is included in the question, it appears that the code is using crc32 code to generate crc16. Based on the crc_result = ... &0x0000FFFF), it appears to be a bit reflected crc. So the polynomial being used is 16 bit instead of 32 bit, and assuming it's a reflected crc, the 16 bit polynomial would be in the lower 32 bits of the polynomial used by the crc32 functions. If this was a non-reflected crc, then the 16 bit polynomial would be in the upper 16 bits of the 32 bit polynomial, and the crc_result = ... >> 16.